# Joint distribution of a non-homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Given a non-homogeneous Poisson process where $X_1$, $X_2$ is the time of first and second point and let $T_1$, $T_2$ ... be the interpoint distances. 
That is, $T_1 = X_1$, $T_2 = X_2-X_1$.

Also, $T_1$, $T_2$ are dependent and they have different distribution.

How should I find the joint distribution of ($T_1$, $T_2$) and ($X_1$, $X_2$)?